# React test case error: Not able to match snapshot

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am trying to write a test case for react component, tried to start with writing a test case for the snapshot, but it is failing.

Following is the code from the test file:

```
describe("Testing signIn component", () => {
    let wrapper: ReactWrapper<any, Readonly<{}>, Component<{}, {}, any>>;

    const ProspectState = {
        prospectSignInError: "",
        prospectSignInSuccess: ""
    }
    // const handleClick = jest.fn()

    beforeEach(() => {
        shallow(<SignIn />);
        wrapper = mount(<BrowserRouter><SignIn /></BrowserRouter>);
    })

    it("should match snapshot", () => { 
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    })
})
```

The error log shows:

```
 20 |     it("should match snapshot", () => {
    > 21 |         expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
         |                         ^
      22 |     })
      23 | })
```

What needs to be changed to just pass the snapshot test?

Comment: What's the error message? Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @slideshowp2 : babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
    Invalid variable access: signInMock